# Can't install express ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried any ways I can but still can't install express successfully. 
I used

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
sudo npm install -g express
```

The terminal shows

```
 /usr/bin/express -> /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
 express-generator@4.13.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator
 ├── sorted-object@1.0.0
 ├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
 └── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

But when I input express, it still says "command not find". I also added the path"/usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin" in system path, it still failed.

I stuck this problem for two days, it's quite annoying. Please help me.

Comment: Don't install as root, install as your own user otherwise you have to run sudo express for it to work.

Comment: Install express first and then the generator. What are your npm & node versions?

Comment: @limelights, thanks. It works as you said.

Comment: @cesarluis.my node is v0.10.37, and npm 1.4.28. I changed the directory and install express, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$ sudo npm cache clean` and then install *express* and *express-generator* without `sudo`.